# Django delete without calling signals

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I use signals for things that should always be done when an object is deleted, saved, updated, etc. However, there are times when I don't want to call my save signals, so I use

`Model.objects.filter(id=instance.id).update(field=value)`

instead of the instance's save method:

`instance.save()`

In the case of deleting objects, there are also times when I don't want to call the delete signals, but I haven't found a way to avoid calling them. Is there a way??

**UPDATE:**

I'm using django 1.6.2 and calling the delete method like this:

`Model.objects.filter(id=instance.id).delete()`

on the queryset still still calls the delete signal.

Answer (score 5):

There is **unsafe** and **undocumented** way which probably can change between versions and also **can lead to unexpected consequences which will be hard to debug**.

This is a hack that probably you don't want to use but.... it's possible.

```
qs = Model.objects.filter(id=instance.id)
qs.order_by().select_related(None)._raw_delete(qs.db)
```

If you have any related objects to this one it will probably fail with database error because records will not be deleted automatically by Django

Comment: Just tried this with django 3.1 -- it initially failed due to a foreign key reference from another table; after I removed that other object, tried a second time and it worked.  If it hadn't work I would have resorted to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

In the place where you don't want signals to be called, you have to disconnect them, run you code and then reconnect them again. You can take a look on how [mute_signal](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/blob/master/factory/django.py#L254) decorator is implemented in FactoryBoy or just use (but it's basically intended for django tests)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
Model.objects.filter(id=instance.id).delete()
```

Comment: Hey, I've tried this too, but it actually does call the delete signal. I'm using django 1.6.2. Updating the question with this now...

Comment: this used to work but queryset delete can trigger signals now https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#delete

Answer (score 0):

Try using raw SQL and don't resist it. It is always a powerful ultimate weapon you could use.

```py
from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(f'DELETE from tbl_model where id={instance.id}')
```